# DLL only readable for one Executable

Tags: vb.net, dll, exe

*Sorry for the title, tell me if it isn't clear.*

So I have an almost finished DLL for my executable. But I got a problem, pretty big. I searched it up on the [internet](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=How%20to%20make%20a%20DLL%20only%20readable%20from%20specific%20executable) but I didn't find it.
Now my problem is that if you have Visual Studio and Visual Basic you can literally use my DLL for other purposes. So is there a way to make it only readable from one program? Companies and developers use DLL's but I can't bind them (C#).

Comment: Rather than readable do you mean usable?  One way is to use ILMerge to merge them into one assembly so there isnt a separate DLL.  I dont know what you mean by that last sentence

Comment: @Plutonix : He probably meant that he cannot add them as a reference. OP: The companies' DLLs are likely written in a language like C or C++, which are compiled directly into machine code. Such DLLs cannot be read by the .NET Framework as a normal reference, and you'd have to P/Invoke them if it's possible.

Comment: I'll react to the questions first. Vincent had it right but I said it is indeed C#, so I should be able to add it as reference. Plutonix, I mean useable yes. But the thing is, I do not want to merge them into one executable. Games use DLL's too for actually one executable. I need that too. and what do you mean with P/Invoke?

Comment: If you only want it to be usable with one program, why make it a dll?

Comment: Because things.. It is possible and I need to know how.

Comment: [P/Invoke - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services).

Comment: ok, that isn't what I meant. I think..

Comment: If I understand you correctly, which I'm not sure I do, then you are thinking that because you have found some DLL's that you can't use, then that is because they are tied to one exe. But that is not the case. You can't reference them because they are written in C or C++ as  Visual said, not because they are in some way tied to a specific exe.